# PayPal-Plus SDK (PHP): How to setup provided payment options?

Tags: php, paypal

This should be quite easy but I sadly can't find an option where I can setup which payment options should be provided for customers.

I got the PayPal-Plus SDK working in my PHP web-shop. My way is the following:

1. I build the Payment-Object and create it
2. I use the Approval-URL from the created payment-object to get the paypal-payment-frame by javascript

Where can I setup which payment-methods (paypal, invoice, credit card, debit) are provided for the customer. Is there an argument to setup in my code or do I have to configure it in my paypal-profile?

Thanks in advance,
Micha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called the Support. There is no way to configure payment methods when you use the "PayPal-Frame". It's all about all or nothing.

This requirement can only be solved when f.e. the REST-API is used where all payment information is sent to PayPal without using any PayPal-provided content.